# Why does a video stream split by a tee show in only one display window?

Tags: gstreamer

I am not yet a genius at gstreamer, but experimenting with the basics to become less ignorant.  I tried this, expecting to see two test patterns in separate pop-up windows:

```
gstl  videotestsrc  ! tee name=t  ! autovideosink   t. ! autovideosink
```

This causes two new windows to pop up, but only one shows the color bars test pattern.  The other shows a frozen snapshot of the desktop background it happened to cover.  Why does this happen, and how would I modify my pipeline to work?

Comment: BTW, 'gstl' is alias for gst-launch-1.0

Answer (score 2):

pls try like this:

gst-launch-1.0  videotestsrc ! tee name=t ! queue ! autovideosink   t. ! queue ! autovideosink

Comment: Can you explain why this works, and what happens when 'queue' is absent?

Comment: A queue adds a thread. When your pipeline is prerolling it waits until all sinks have received data. With no queue the first output pad of your tee sends data to the sink - that sinks blocks and waits and because of that prevents the tee from sending data to the second output pad. A thread will allow this so both sinks will get data and you can switch from prerolling to playing state.

Comment: when 'queue' is absent, the pipeline will work in push mode. becase the tee element exist, the first sink element's chain func will block the source element's pad-push func, the second sink element cann't complete preroll.
refer to:
https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/design/preroll.html#preroll
https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/application-development/advanced/threads.html#scheduling-in-gstreamer